# Using Postman-GRPC ,I need to upload a file as request(via postman) to the my GRPC-server

Tags: asp.net-core, postman, grpc, grpc-web, grpc-c#

I have a GRPC file-upload server(C#) running and I also have GRPC-client through which I was uploading files to the GRPC server but now I want to upload my file using postman(yes the new postman version supports GRPC) and now I am not able to figure out how to attach/send the file via the GRPC-postman to my GRPC-server ,for example in REST-postman u r able attach the file in body using FORM-DATA tab. can anyone give me a solution to this

Thank you